# Deserializing ImmutableList using Gson

Tags: java, adapter, immutability, gson

I'm using quite a few immutable collections and I'm curious how to deserialize them using Gson. As nobody answered and I've found the solution myself, I'm simplifying the question and presenting my own answer.

I had two problems:

- How to write a single `Deserializer` working for all `ImmutableList<XXX>`?
- How to register it for all `ImmutableList<XXX>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: There's https://github.com/acebaggins/gson-serializers which covers many guava collections:

- `ImmutableList`
- `ImmutableSet`
- `ImmutableSortedSet`
- `ImmutableMap`
- `ImmutableSortedMap`

---

> How to write a single Deserializer working for all ImmutableList?

The idea is simple, transform the passed `Type` representing an `ImmutableList<T>` into a `Type` representing `List<T>`, use the build-in `Gson`'s capability to create a `List` and convert it to an `ImmutableList`.

```
class MyJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ImmutableList<?>> {
    @Override
    public ImmutableList<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final Type type2 = ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List.class, ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments(), null);
        final List<?> list = context.deserialize(json, type2);
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
    }
}
```

There are multiple `ParameterizedTypeImpl` classes in Java libraries I use, but none of them intended for public usage. I tested it with `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl`.

> How to register it for all ImmutableList?

That part is trivial, the first argument to register is `java.lang.reflect.Type` which mislead me to using `ParameterizedType`, where simply using `Class` does the job:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(ImmutableList.class, myJsonDeserializer)
    .create();
```

Comment: Can we avoid using of ParameterizedTypeImpl? For example using smth like:
final List<?> list = context.deserialize(json, List.class);

Comment: @Alexander Bezrodniy: I'm afraid, it's not possible. You can avoid it all by using a `TypeAdapter<ImmutableList<T>>`, but then you have to write some other boilerplate code: 1. Implement `write` even though the default implementation would suffice, 2. Deal with `null` in `read`. It's all a bit low level stuff.

Comment: I guess now I understand your question. You can't leave out the generics; without them the list content can't be deserialized properly.

Comment: @maaartinus is this not an issue? "ParameterizedTypeImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

Comment: @Riaan Sure, it may be, but Java is very conservative and if it gets removed, you'll probably find another one. Or better, use one of the other answers. *At the time of my posting, I didn't knew better (maybe it wasn't even possible). Now, I can't fix my answer without duplicating another one.*

Comment: @maaartinus (and everyone else using this solution), please prefer using [`TypeToken.getParameterized`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#getParameterized-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type...-)  which has been recently added to Gson and is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

One more implementation without ParameterizedTypeImpl

```
@Override
public ImmutableList<?> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final TypeToken<ImmutableList<?>> immutableListToken = (TypeToken<ImmutableList<?>>) TypeToken.of(type);
    final TypeToken<? super ImmutableList<?>> listToken = immutableListToken.getSupertype(List.class);
    final List<?> list = context.deserialize(json, listToken.getType());
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
}
```

Comment: Any way this can be updated for latest version of Gson?

Comment: @lostintranslation, what's wrong with current implementation? I've checked and it works for 2.8.5 version.

Comment: @komarik, the problem is that the used `TypeToken` is the one from guava. Gson's `TypeToken` does not have a `getSupertype` method (at least in 2.8.5). However, recently the method [`getParameterized`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#getParameterized-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type...-) was added which can be used here.

Answer (score 3):

@maaartinus already covered the second question, so I'll post a complementary Guava-based solution to the first question which doesn't require `ParametrizedTypeImpl`

```
public final class ImmutableListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ImmutableList<?>> {
  @Override
  public ImmutableList<?> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type,
                                      final JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
    final Type[] typeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments();
    final Type parameterizedType = listOf(typeArguments[0]).getType();
    final List<?> list = context.deserialize(json, parameterizedType);
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
  }

  private static <E> TypeToken<List<E>> listOf(final Type arg) {
    return new TypeToken<List<E>>() {}
        .where(new TypeParameter<E>() {}, (TypeToken<E>) TypeToken.of(arg));   
  }
}
```