# How to serialize Optional<T> classes with Gson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have an object with the following attributes.

```
private final String messageBundle;
private final List<String> messageParams;
private final String actionBundle;
private final Map<String, String> data;
private final Optional<Pair<Integer,TimeUnit>> ttl;
private final Optional<Integer> badgeNumber;
private final Optional<String> collapseKey;
```

The object is in a library, i would rather not modify it just for serialization purpose, and would like to avoid the cost of creating another DTO.

How can i serialize / unserialize Optional attributes? Optional doesn't have a default constructor (neither apache commons Pair), but i can't use the InstanceCreator, and don't really understand how to create a TypeAdapter that would simply delegate the serialization to the underlying Optional content.

Comment: Optional shouldn't be used on properties or parameters, just in return types.

Comment: @sargue I think there are valid scenarios when this may be an option. For example you are writing a library for an api service with optional params. So you have to distinguish default value from value set by user

Comment: I'm not saying it, the javadocs says it:
Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null is likely to cause errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution by Ilya ignores type parameters, so it can't really work in the general case. My solution is rather complicated, because of the need to distinguish between `null` and `Optional.absent()` -- otherwise you could strip away the encapsulation as a list.

```
public class GsonOptionalDeserializer<T>
implements JsonSerializer<Optional<T>>, JsonDeserializer<Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    public Optional<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonArray asJsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
        final JsonElement jsonElement = asJsonArray.get(0);
        final T value = context.deserialize(jsonElement, ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        return Optional.fromNullable(value);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Optional<T> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonElement element = context.serialize(src.orNull());
        final JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
        result.add(element);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to register a new instance of `GsonOptionalDeserializer` for every type of `Optional` that you want to serialize?

Comment: @scompt.com No, it's just like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7773201/581205).

Comment: Ah, I see. I ended up implementing `TypeAdapterFactory` and doing something similar to the [Multiset example](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) in the Javadocs.

Comment: Looks like during deserialization, this still doesn't distinguish between `Optional.absent()` and `null` since it returns a non-null `Optional` in all cases.

Comment: @JackEdmonds Indeed and it can't as it'd need different representations for `Optional.absent()` and `null`. You could solve it by using a single-element array instead (as `Optional` is an up-to-one-element collection), but OTOH, `Optional` is nothing but exploded `@Nullable` and having `@Nullable Optional` is just plain wrong.

Comment: Note that the encapsulation with an array is only needed when implementing `JsonDeserializer` (see also [this Gson issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1697)). The higher voted answer below uses `TypeAdapter` and therefore does not require this encapsulation and allows to write `"myfield": null` for an absent Optional.

Comment: @Marcono1234 But someone may expect `"myfield": null` to be transformed into `null` (sure, a nullable Optional is stupid..., stupid like.... like Optional itself :D). As I wrote... *"otherwise you could strip away the encapsulation as a list."* I'd bet, my solution could do this... what I don't understand is why the other answer is much longer. I didn't touch Gson for ages...

Answer (score 24):

After several hours of gooling and coding - there is my version:

```
public class OptionalTypeAdapter<E> extends TypeAdapter<Optional<E>> {

    public static final TypeAdapterFactory FACTORY = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
            if (rawType != Optional.class) {
                return null;
            }
            final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type.getType();
            final Type actualType = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            final TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(actualType));
            return new OptionalTypeAdapter(adapter);
        }
    };
    private final TypeAdapter<E> adapter;

    public OptionalTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<E> adapter) {

        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Optional<E> value) throws IOException {
        if(value.isPresent()){
            adapter.write(out, value.get());
        } else {
            out.nullValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final JsonToken peek = in.peek();
        if(peek != JsonToken.NULL){
            return Optional.ofNullable(adapter.read(in));
        }

        in.nextNull();
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

You can simple registered it with `GsonBuilder` like this:

```
instance.registerTypeAdapterFactory(OptionalTypeAdapter.FACTORY)
```

Please keep attention that Gson does not set values to your class field if field does not present in json. So you need to set default value `Optional.empty()` in your entity.

Comment: `read(...)` is not consuming the `null`. It should call `skipValue()` or `nextNull()`.

Comment: @Marcono1234  I fixed this and providing TypeAdapter for List, here is my full code: https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/319de4c73f7269d197a2a3fe4523a1f7

Answer (score 4):

Just as an addition to maaartinus solution, the version without the encapsulating list, where `Optional.absent` is simply serialized as `null`:

```
public class GsonOptionalDeserializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<Optional<T>>, JsonDeserializer<Optional<T>> {
    @Override
    public Optional<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
        final T value = context.deserialize(json, ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        return Optional.fromNullable(value);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Optional<T> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(src.orNull());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than the answer. The JsonArray is not required. Note that this answer is about Guava optionals. For Java8 optionals, use `Optional.ofNullable(value)` and `src.orElse(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to [Anton Onikiychuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153327/anton-onikiychuk)'s answer

```
@Override
public Optional<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    JsonToken peek = in.peek();
    if (peek == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull(); // consuming JSON null
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.ofNullable(adapter.read(in));
}
```

Comment: That's a good and important point! Though it would probably have been better to add that as comment or propose it as edit. I have proposed an edit solving this now.

Answer (score 1):

I dearly feel that its important for the reader which ends up in this thread to know at the time this answer is written, none of the solutions offered in the current answers actually solve the original requirement placed in the question.

TLDR Switch to `Jackson`

- Requirement cannot be satisfied with `Gson` (at least not with the latest version in the time this answer is written that is 2.10.1).
- All the offered solutions so far lead to the same result - upon parsing a json string, when an attribute is missing, even if the corresponding java entity class member type is `Optional<?>`, at the end of the de-serialization the member will end up referring a `null` and not an `Optional.empty()` as desired, leading to `NullPointerException` when retrieving the Optional member.
- If you insist on using Gson, you'll have to manually address the scenarios where the optional attribute is absent within the entity class member getter i.e.

  ```
  public Optional<String> myOptionalString() {
       return this.myOptionalString == null ? Optional.empty() : myOptionalString
  }
  ```
- Me personally, I ended up ditching `Gson` in favor of `Jackson`, which together with its `Jdk8Module`, solves the problem.
- In Jackson, you'll create the `ObjectMapper` this way

  ```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  ```

  And then you'll parse your json string into an entity this way

  ```
  mapper.readValue(jsonWithOptionals, EntityWithOptionals.class)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar challenge when trying to create a custom Gson TypeAdapter for optional types like java.util.Optional. Despite searching extensively and reviewing existing answers, I couldn't find a solution that precisely addressed this issue.

However, after thorough experimentation, I've managed to create a custom TypeAdapter that should work for your scenario:

```
/**
 * TypeAdapter to manage nullable fields with Optional approach
 */
public static class OptionalTypeAdapter<E> implements JsonSerializer<Optional<E>>, JsonDeserializer<Optional<E>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Optional<E> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (src.isPresent()) {
            return context.serialize(src.get());
        } else {
            return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonNull()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            E value = context.deserialize(json, ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            return Optional.ofNullable(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This custom OptionalTypeAdapter should allow Gson to handle optional types appropriately in serialization and deserialization.

Instance a Gson object to handle JSON is now possible through this code:

```
new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapter(Optional.class, new OptionalTypeAdapter<>())
.create();
```