# Could i serialize into a json only the value from a java.util.Optional?

Tags: java, json, serialization, java-8

I face the following problem : i have a class that has as data members java.util.Optional objects and i need to put transform that into a json.
The code looks in a generic way like this:

```
public class MyClass{

  public java.util.Optional<MyCustomObject> object;

  public Myclass(java.util.Optional<MyCustomObject> object){
    this.object = object;
  }

  public java.util.Optional<MyCustomObject> getObject(){
    return this.object;
  }

  public void setObject(java.util.Optional<MyCustomObject> object){
    return this.object = object;
  }
}
```

When i turn this into a json i get something like this:

```
Optional[
                object
            ]
```

I want to get rid of that Optional part from the json.
Could i do that?

Comment: And what JSON library do you use?

Comment: Pleas show your code for making the json from this.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `MyCustomObject` into an `Optional` in the first place? Your use counteracts the intention of `Optional` completely as you are introducing another variable, `MyClass.object` which can be `null`…

Comment: If you're using Jackson, you could add a custom type converter for `Optional`, but Holger is right that Optional is redundant in the first place.

Comment: Well it might be redundant, but this is the case that i have to deal with, if you say Jackson, then i'll have a look at that.

Comment: If you are using Gson [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161366/how-to-serialize-optionalt-classes-with-gson) might help. It appears to be using the Optional from Guava but the idea will be the same. I believe the redundant comment stems from the fact that you allow MyClass.object to be null. You should change the Ctor and setObject methods to take in MyCutsomObject instead of Optional<MyCustomObject> then construct the Optional wrapper yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple Java libraries available for serialization/deserialization. One of these is the [excellent Jackson library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) where you can tune your serialization in a fine grained way.

If you own the source code of the POJO `MyClass` you can simply add some annotations to get it to work properly.

If you assume that `MyCustomObject` looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomObject {
    private final String myVal;

    public MyCustomObject(String myVal) {
        this.myVal = myVal;
    }

    public String getMyVal() {
        return myVal;
    }
}
```

Then, your `MyClass` object can be declared like this (notice the [annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty`):

```
public class MyClass {
    private Optional<MyCustomObject> object;

    public MyClass(Optional<MyCustomObject> object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    // Ignore the "normal" serialization
    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<MyCustomObject> getObject() {
        return this.object;
    }

    public void setObject(Optional<MyCustomObject> object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    // This handles the serialization
    @JsonProperty("object")
    private MyCustomObject getObjectAndYesThisIsAPrivateMethod() {
        return getObject().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use the following code for serializing to JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(
        new MyClass(Optional.ofNullable(new MyCustomObject("Yes, my value!"))));
```

The *magic* in the code above lies in the use of the [ObjectMapper](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/ObjectMapper) which handles the data binding i.e. converting between POJOs and JSON (and vice versa).

---

Another approach, if you do not own the source code of the `MyClass` class i.e. you can not modify it is to create a custom serializer [as described in the Jackson docs](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).