# Gson deserialization: How to distinguish between fields that are missing and fields that are explicitly set to null?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to implement [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) for a Java (JAX-RS) webservice I'm building.

The gist is that partial updates of a record are done by sending a JSON document to the server that only contains the fields that should be changed.

Given this record

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": {
    "d": "e",
    "f": "g"
  }
}
```

, the following JSON update document

```
{
  "a":"z",
  "c": {
    "f": null
  }
}
```

should set a new value for `"a"`  and delete `"f"` inside `"c"`.

**The latter is the problem. I don't know how I can distinguish between an input where f is missing and an input where f is null.** Both, as far as I can tell, would be deserialized to `null` in the target Java Object.

What do?

Comment: no good way, xml world has xsi:nil="true", in java if something is null, you dont know if it was initialized to null or someone set it as null, you could define enum if possible and assign empty value

Comment: I was considering writing my own deserializer for Java 8's [Optional<Type>](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).

Comment: Hm. I tried that, but got stuck fairly quickly due to Java's type erasure. I can't implement a ``Serializer`` (or deserializer) for ``Optional<T>`` because the signature doesn't match, and I can't implement a ``TypeAdapterFactory`` because I can't get hold of the type parameter of ``Optional`` at runtime. Very, very frustrating.

Comment: I also tried wrapping ``Optional<T>`` in a class that explicitly remembers its original type by requiring it as a constructor parameter. This might work, but the code to initialize (or retrieve) a simple string becomes horribly long and twisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I acknowledge mlk's answer, but given that I already have (and would nonetheless need) a POJO representation of the JSON object, I feel mapping automatically is still better than looking up manually.

The challenge with that is that, as I said, **both missing and explicit null values are set to null in the corresponding POJO** that `gson.fromJson(...)` would populate. (Unlike e.g. R's `NULL` and `NA`, Java only has one representation for "not there".)

However, by modelling my data structure using [Java 8's Optionals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) I can do just that: Distinguish between something that is not set, and something that is set to `null`. Here's what I ended up with:

1) I replaced all fields in my data objects with `Optional<T>`.

```
public class BasicObjectOptional {

    private Optional<String> someKey;
    private Optional<Integer> someNumber;
    private Optional<String> mayBeNull;

    public BasicObjectOptional() {
    }

    public BasicObjectOptional(boolean initialize) {
        if (initialize) {
            someKey = Optional.ofNullable("someValue");
            someNumber = Optional.ofNullable(42);
            mayBeNull = Optional.ofNullable(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("someKey = %s, someNumber = %s, mayBeNull = %s",
                                            someKey, someNumber, mayBeNull);
    }

}
```

Or a nested one:

```
public class ComplexObjectOptional {

    Optional<String> theTitle;  
    Optional<List<Optional<String>>> stringArray;
    Optional<BasicObjectOptional> theObject;

    public ComplexObjectOptional() {
    }

    public ComplexObjectOptional(boolean initialize) {
        if (initialize) {
            theTitle = Optional.ofNullable("Complex Object");   
            stringArray =    Optional.ofNullable(Arrays.asList(Optional.ofNullable("Hello"),Optional.ofNullable("World")));
            theObject = Optional.ofNullable(new BasicObjectOptional(true));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("theTitle = %s, stringArray = %s, theObject = (%s)", theTitle, stringArray, theObject);
    }   
}
```

2) Implemented a serializer and deserializer [based on this useful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078422/2446808).

```
public class OptionalTypeAdapter<E> extends TypeAdapter<Optional<E>> {

    public static final TypeAdapterFactory FACTORY = new TypeAdapterFactory() {

        //@Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
            if (rawType != Optional.class) {
                return null;
            }
            final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type.getType();
            final Type actualType = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            final TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(actualType));
            return new OptionalTypeAdapter(adapter);
        }
    };
    private final TypeAdapter<E> adapter;

    public OptionalTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<E> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Optional<E> value) throws IOException {
        if(value == null || !value.isPresent()){
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            adapter.write(out, value.get());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final JsonToken peek = in.peek();
        if(peek != JsonToken.NULL){
            return Optional.ofNullable(adapter.read(in));
        }
        in.nextNull();
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

3) Registered this adapter when initializing Gson.

```
Gson gsonOptFact = new GsonBuilder()
    .serializeNulls() // matter of taste, just for output anyway
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(OptionalTypeAdapter.FACTORY)
    .create();
```

This allows me to write JSON such that both `null` and empty `Optional` are serialized as `null` (or simply removed from the output), while at the same time reading JSON into `Optional` fields such that **if the field is `null` I know it was missing from the JSON input, and if the field is `Optional.empty` I know it was set to `null` in the input.**

---

Example:

```
System.out.println(gsonOptFact.toJson(new BasicObjectOptional(true)));
// {"someKey":"someValue","someNumber":42,"mayBeNull":null}

System.out.println(gsonOptFact.toJson(new ComplexObjectOptional(true)));
// {"theTitle":"Complex Object","stringArray":["Hello","World"],"theObject":{"someKey":"someValue","someNumber":42,"mayBeNull":null}}

// Now read back in:
String basic = "{\"someKey\":\"someValue\",\"someNumber\":42,\"mayBeNull\":null}";
String complex = "{\"theTitle\":\"Complex Object\",\"stringArray\":[\"Hello\",\"world\"],\"theObject\":{\"someKey\":\"someValue\",\"someNumber\":42,\"mayBeNull\":null}}";
String complexMissing = "{\"theTitle\":\"Complex Object\",\"theObject\":{\"someKey\":\"someValue\",\"mayBeNull\":null}}";

BasicObjectOptional boo = gsonOptFact.fromJson(basic, BasicObjectOptional.class);
System.out.println(boo);
// someKey = Optional[someValue], someNumber = Optional[42], mayBeNull = Optional.empty

ComplexObjectOptional coo = gsonOptFact.fromJson(complex, ComplexObjectOptional.class);
System.out.println(coo);
// theTitle = Optional[Complex Object], stringArray = Optional[[Optional[Hello], Optional[world]]], theObject = (Optional[someKey = Optional[someValue], someNumber = Optional[42], mayBeNull = Optional.empty])

ComplexObjectOptional coom = gsonOptFact.fromJson(complexMissing, ComplexObjectOptional.class);
System.out.println(coom);
// theTitle = Optional[Complex Object], stringArray = null, theObject = (Optional[someKey = Optional[someValue], someNumber = null, mayBeNull = Optional.empty])
```

I think this will allow me to integrate JSON Merge Patch with my existing data objects quite well.

Comment: Some perspective after a bit of time has passed: We have used this solution quite successfully for roughly half a year now, but we're going to migrate to Jackson instead of Gson for unrelated reasons. Upside: Jackson does this out of the box, distinguishing between ``null`` and "not sent".

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and look at the Json object returned.

You can using [`JsonParser.parse(java.io.Reader)`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse(java.io.Reader)) to get the JsonObject.

Comment: Where, or how, would I do that? Currently I'm parsing input directly to domain objects using something like ``MyObject bla = gson.fromJson(someStream, MyObject.class);``

Comment: OK, so you're saying instead of mapping the JSON to a domain object, I could just "open" it in the parser and traverse it and look up the elements I'm interested in.

Comment: Aye. I think you could do something with a custom deserializer. I don't think you can use `Optional<T>` as you need to have three states - Sent and `null`, sent and value and not sent.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I just submitted. I think I can use ``Optional.empty`` along with ``null`` (either inside the Optional or instead of it, the latter being Gson's default behavior) to model three states. I have to test this a bit more, but I think it can work.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive types, use the nullable version.

Example, use Long where you would normally use long.  Integer replaced int, etc.

You can also use String type where you want to detect missing values but then you would also need to parse the String into the type you need.

Comment: I'm not sure this would solve the problem. I needed to distinguish, even only for primitives, three cases: 1: The client sent a value, which may be "0" (asking me to replace the value that was there before). 2: The client actively sent "null" (i.e. asking me to delete what was there before). 3: The client didn't send a new value (i.e. I'm not supposed to touch what I already have).

Comment: Ah, in my case I only needed to detect missing values.  For primitives the above worked and for custom types. they are null when not provided. 

You are correct; this will not be able to detect a value that is missing vs one that was included in the JSON as null.