# Skip serializing GSON field in generics based on value

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, gson

We have the need to distinguish between an optional fields vs. nullable fields (i.e when a field is present, that it could be nullable) when serializing Kotlin data classes to JSON using GSON.

The initial thought was to model the optional field as a generic:

```
class Optional<T>(val isPresent: Boolean = false, val value: T) {}
```

That would permit representing it in the following serializable data class:

```
data class SimpleRequest (
    val a: Int = 0,
    val b: Optional<String> = Optional<String>(value = "")
    val c: Optional<String> = Optional<String>(value = "")
    val d: Int? = null,
    val e: Optional<Int?> = Optional<Int?>(value = null)
)
```

That should result in the following serialized variants (with null serialization enabled):

```
SimpleRequest(c = Optional<String>(true, "Hello"), e = Optional(true, null))
```

```
{
   "a": 0,
   "c": "Hello",
   "d": null,
   "e": null
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For the case `e = Optional(true, null)`, how would you tell apart a `null` value with `isPresent=true` and a `null` value with `isPresent=false`; in JSON both would just be `null`, wouldn't they?

Comment: When isPresent is false, no value will be emitted in the JSON (hence why “b” was omitted in the encoding above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom `TypeAdapterFactory` for your `Optional` type would probably be similar to what [has been suggested for `java.util.Optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12161366).

To omit the property from JSON even with `GsonBuilder.serializeNulls()` being enabled, you could choose a similar approach as in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1558#issuecomment-578435043), where the author temporarily calls `JsonWriter.setSerializeNulls(false)` if the value is `null` before restoring the previous setting again. In your case you could do that when `isPresent == false`.

If you also want to cover deserialization, then you might have to switch to another JSON library because...

- Gson's main focus is on Java, and it does not support Kotlin that well, see [this issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1657) about default values and `null` handling
- Gson currently does not allow to handle missing field values ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1005)), so you would have to make sure a proper default value is set

Comment: The combination of the two did the trick! Thanks a ton!!