# Why does GSON expect BEGIN_OBJECT when I've explicitly defined my variable as STRING?

Tags: java, gson

This is the error log I've gotten when i tried to do `gson.fromJson(bodyString, output);`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 203 path $.pending[1].date
```

The json `body` in question is the following:

```
{
    "id": "OOOO1234",
    "pending": [
        {
            "req_id": "ABCDF173821-399",
            "status": "1",
            "date": "2023-11-24"
        }
    ]
}
```

`bodyString` is:

```
{\"id\":\"OOOO1234\",\"pending\":[{\"req_id\":\"ABCDF173821-399\",\"status\":\"1\",\"date\":\"2023-11-24\"}]}
```

And here are the `output` java classes:

```
@Builder
  class Output {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @NonNull
    public final String id;
  
    @SerializedName("pending")
    public final List<Pending> pending;
  }
    
@Builder
  class Pending {
    @SerializedName("req_id")
    public final String reqId;
  
    @SerializedName("status")
    public final String status;
  
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Builder.Default
    public final Optional<String> date = Optional.empty();
  }
```

I'm expecting no errors thrown when converting my json body string to my data class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize Optional<T> classes with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161366/how-to-serialize-optionalt-classes-with-gson)

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate; the underlying issue is that Gson has no built-in adapter for `java.util.Optional` yet so it tries to deserialize it as JSON object instead of just deserializing the wrapped type (`String` in your case).