# Simpler use of TypeAdapterFactory

Tags: java, adapter, gson

AFAIK the most flexible gson customization is possible via `TypeAdapterFactory`, however it may get needlessly complicated. It forces me to write for each handled class both `read` and `write`, while sometimes only one method is really needed. Moreover, sometimes a `JsonSerializer` and/or `JsonDeserializer` were much easier to write, e.g. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773201/581205). This leads me to these questions:

- Is it possible to write a `TypeAdapter` which simply delegates one of its methods (e.g. writing of `ImmutableList` to writing of `List`)?
- Is it possible to somehow use `JsonSerializer` and/or `JsonDeserializer` together with the `TypeAdapterFactory`? Alternatively, is there a factory for them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to create a `TypeAdapter` that delegates one of its methods. This use case is an important part of the API, and there's a [getDelegateAdapter()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter%28com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory,%20com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken%29) method for just this purpose. Pass `this` as the first argument to `getDelegateAdapter` which will return the adapter that takes precedence after the current factory.

```
TypeAdapterFactory immutableListFactory = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
  @Override public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    if (!(type.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType)
        || !type.getRawType().equals(ImmutableList.class)) {
      return null;
    }

    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type.getType();
    TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
    TypeAdapter<?> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(
        TypeToken.get(parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]));
    return new ImmutableListAdapter(delegate, elementAdapter);
  }

  class ImmutableListAdapter<E> extends TypeAdapter<ImmutableList<E>> {
    private TypeAdapter<List<E>> delegate;
    private TypeAdapter<E> element;

    ImmutableListAdapter(TypeAdapter<List<E>> delegate, TypeAdapter<E> element) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
      this.element = element;
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, ImmutableList<E> value) throws IOException {
      delegate.write(out, value);
    }

    @Override public ImmutableList<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      ImmutableList.Builder<E> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
      in.beginArray();
      while (in.hasNext()) {
        builder.add(element.read(in));
      }
      in.endArray();
      return builder.build();
    }
  }
};
```

You can mix and match `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` with `TypeAdapterFactory`, but not directly. The simplest way is to call back into Gson to serialize child values in your class. In this example we'd change the inner loop to this:

```
      while (in.hasNext()) {
        builder.add(gson.<E>fromJson(in, elementType));
      }
```

The main difference between `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` and `TypeAdapter` is how many stages it takes to go from JSON to your object model. With `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` objects are first converted to Gson's DOM model (`JsonElement` etc.) and then converted into your object model. With `TypeAdapter`, the intermediate step is skipped.

This makes the type adapter code a little trickier to read and write, so you should prefer it only for optimized code.

Comment: This is a great answer.  One of the hundred best I have read on this site over the years.  Thanks for taking the time to provide a realistic example!  This answer single-handedly changed my view of Gson.