# Gson: Custom deserialization if certain field is present

Tags: deserialization, gson, jsonreader

I have a class that looks as follows

```
class Person {
    Long id;
    String firstName;
    int age;
}
```

and my input either looks like this:

```
{ "id": null, "firstName": "John", "age": 10 }
```

or like this:

```
{ "id": 123 }
```

The first variant represents a "new" (non-persisted) person and the second refers to a person by its database id.

If `id` is non-null, I would like to load the object from database during deserialization, otherwise fallback on regular parsing and deserialize it as a new object.

**What I've tried:** I currently have a `JsonDeserializer` for database-deserialization, but as I understand it, there is no way to "fall back" on regular parsing. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574931/simpler-use-of-typeadapterfactory) I should use a `TypeAdapterFactory` and the [`getDelegateAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter%28com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory,%20com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken%29). My problem with this approach is that I'm given a `JsonReader` (and not for instance a `JsonElement`) so I can't determine if the input contains a valid `id` without consuming input.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to figure this out with the help of the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272452/276052).

Here is a working type adapter factory:

```
new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter =
                    gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

            // Are we asked to parse a person?
            if (!type.getType().equals(Person.class))
                return null;

            return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

                @Override
                public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

                    JsonElement tree = elementAdapter.read(reader);
                    JsonElement id = tree.getAsJsonObject().get("id");

                    if (id == null)
                        return delegate.fromJsonTree(tree);

                    return (T) findObj(id.getAsLong());
                }

                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter writer, T obj) throws IOException {
                    delegate.write(writer, obj);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

I haven't fully tested it yet and I'll get back and revise it if needed. (Posting it now to open up for feed back on the approach.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but if you already have a `JsonDeserializer`, you should have a method like this one in there:

```
public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) { ... }
```

In this method you have the object `context` of type `JsonDeserializationContext`, which allows you to invoke default deserialization on a specified object.

So, you could do something like inside your custom deserializer:

```
//If id is null...
Person person = context.deserialize(json, Person.class);
```

See [`JsonDeserializationContext` documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializationContext.html).

Comment: I tried precisely this, but I get a StackOverflowException due to an endless recursion. I think the context represents "this" gson, and not what this gson would have been without this type-adapter.

Comment: @aioobe: and what about creating a new `Gson` object within the `JsonDeserializer` and do `Person person = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class);`?

Comment: Right, that would have worked for the simple example I wrote in my question. However, in my actual code I have references to other objects (suppose for instance that a `Person` would have a reference to a `Person parent`). If we delegate the parsing of a person to another `gson` object, the *parent* couldn't be loaded from the database.