# Deserialize to an ImmutableMap with GSON

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I'd like to use GSON to derialize:

```
"starterItems": {
    "Appeltaart": 3,
    "Soap_50": 3
}
```

...into a Guava `ImmutableMap`:

```
private ImmutableMap<String,Integer> starterItems;
```

I thought I'd just use regular GSON map parsing, then make an immutable copy of the result, like this:

```
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(ImmutableMap.class, new JsonDeserializer<ImmutableMap>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override public ImmutableMap deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return ImmutableMap.copyOf((Map) context.deserialize(json, Map.class));
        }
    });
```

But as expected, that was too simple (there is no type information). I get the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer MapTypeAdapter failed to deserialized json object {"Appeltaart":3,"Soap_50":3} given the type interface java.util.Map
```

Can I do what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that straightforward, since you would want to maintain the type parameters in order to build a map containing the right types. To do that, you can go with a `TypeAdapterFactory`, and ask there for a delegate `TypeAdapter`, using the fully specified `TypeToken`.

```
public class ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public static final ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory INSTANCE = new ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory();

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (!ImmutableMap.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                return (T) ImmutableMap.copyOf((Map) delegate.read(in));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now you have another problem: the default GSON `MapTypeAdapterFactory` will try to create an instance of `ImmutableMap`, and modify it. This obviously won't work. You should create a `TypeToken<HashMap<K, V>>` from the `TypeToken<ImmutableMap<K, V>>`, but I honestly don't know how you can do that. Instead, you can use an `InstanceCreator` to trick GSON into building a `HashMap` when an `ImmutableMap` is actually required:

```
public static <K,V> InstanceCreator<Map<K, V>> newCreator() {
    return new InstanceCreator<Map<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<K, V> createInstance(Type type) {
            return new HashMap<K, V>();
        }
    };
}
```

Clearly you have to register both the TypeAdapterFactory and the InstanceCreator:

```
GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory());
b.registerTypeAdapter(ImmutableMap.class, ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory.newCreator());
```

Comment: Found a simple change that makes my initial idea work, which is good enough for my needs at the moment. Yours appears to be more generic though, so better in the end.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap() with no args at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:94)".

Comment: Haven't found the time (or need) to test this yet, but it's been so long, you deserve that check mark :)

Answer (score 5):

Google's Caliper project (micro-benchmarker for Java) has one:
https://github.com/google/caliper/blob/master/caliper/src/main/java/com/google/caliper/json/ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory.java

Reference (in case it moves, or is deleted in the future):

```
/**
 * Serializes and deserializes {@link ImmutableMap} instances using a {@link HashMap} as an
 * intermediary.
 */
final class ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    Type type = typeToken.getType();
    if (typeToken.getRawType() != ImmutableMap.class
        || !(type instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
      return null;
    }

    com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<ImmutableMap<?, ?>> betterToken =
        (com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<ImmutableMap<?, ?>>)
            com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.of(typeToken.getType());
    final TypeAdapter<HashMap<?, ?>> hashMapAdapter =
        (TypeAdapter<HashMap<?, ?>>) gson.getAdapter(
            TypeToken.get(betterToken.getSupertype(Map.class).getSubtype(HashMap.class)
                .getType()));
    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
      @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        HashMap<?, ?> hashMap = Maps.newHashMap((Map<?, ?>) value);
        hashMapAdapter.write(out, hashMap);
      }

      @Override public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        HashMap<?, ?> hashMap = hashMapAdapter.read(in);
        return (T) ImmutableMap.copyOf(hashMap);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The class moved to https://github.com/google/caliper/blob/master/caliper-util/src/main/java/com/google/caliper/json/ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory.java

Comment: I like their approach of using a delegate adapter. I think it would be better to use LinkedHashMap to preserve order.

Comment: @nivs: Excellent point.  Also, `ImmutableMap` guarantees iterator order will match insert (builder add) order -- like `LinkedHashMap`!

Answer (score 2):

This works for ImmutableMap as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773201/342947

```
public final static class ImmutableMapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ImmutableMap<?,?>> {
    @Override
    public ImmutableMap<?,?> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type,
                                       final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        final Type type2 =
            ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(Map.class, ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments(), null);
        final Map<?,?> map = context.deserialize(json, type2);
        return ImmutableMap.copyOf(map);
    }
}

gBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ImmutableMap.class, new GsonUtils.ImmutableMapDeserializer());
```

Answer (score 1):

It works when you add the required type information:

```
gb.registerTypeAdapter(
    new TypeToken<ImmutableMap<String,Integer>>(){}.getType(), 
    new JsonDeserializer<ImmutableMap>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public ImmutableMap deserialize(JsonElement json, 
                                            Type typeOfT, 
                                            JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
                return ImmutableMap.copyOf(
                    (Map) context.deserialize(json, new TypeToken<Map<String,Integer>>(){}.getType()));
            }
        });
```

However, that requires duplicating that code for all types of maps that should be supported. In that regard Flavio's answers is probably the more generic one.

Answer (score 1):

Just is based off of Flavio's answer but in a quick 2-step copy and paste format.

1. Create `GsonUtils` class (which I've included below)
2. Replace all instances of `new Gson()` with `GsonUtils.get()`

*GsonUtils.java*:

```
package com.innomatixdata.busscan.utils;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.InstanceCreator;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Use this class to get an instance of Gson that is configured for this application.
 */
public class GsonUtils {

    private static final GsonBuilder GSON_BUILDER = new GsonBuilder();

    static {
        GSON_BUILDER.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory());
        GSON_BUILDER.registerTypeAdapter(ImmutableMap.class, ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory.newCreator());
    }

    public static Gson get() {
        return GSON_BUILDER.create();
    }

    public static class ImmutableMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            if (!ImmutableMap.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
                return null;
            }
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                    delegate.write(out, value);
                }

                @Override
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    return (T) ImmutableMap.copyOf((Map) delegate.read(in));
                }
            };
        }

        public static <K,V> InstanceCreator<Map<K, V>> newCreator() {
            return new InstanceCreator<Map<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public Map<K, V> createInstance(Type type) {
                    return new HashMap<K, V>();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Flavio's answer, it is possible to change the raw type of the TypeToken which is passed to `getDelegateAdapter()`, making the InstanceCreator unnecessary.

```
final TypeToken<T> mapType = (TypeToken<T>) TypeToken.getParameterized(Map.class,
        ((ParameterizedType) type.getType()).getActualTypeArguments());
final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, mapType);
```