# How to get object from json string, for Java class containing a list, generated using Immutables?

Tags: java, json, gson

my use case included a similar class, using immutables (https://immutables.github.io/) :

```
@Value.Immutable
@Gson.TypeAdapters
public abstract class SampleClass {
    public abstract String var1();
    public abstract String var2();
    public abstract Date date1();
}
```

I was converting it to Json string,using gson, and then getting the object again using :

```
SampleClass obj1 = new Gson().fromJson("generated_json_string",ImmutableSampleClass.class);
```

But now I had to change var1 to List of String, and now I am getting :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList() with no args
```

What is the correct way to get the object from JSON string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong, hence answering the question.
Immutables generated class GsonAdaptersSampleClass, which implements TypeAdapterFactory. Using this and with the help of this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624060/3192744

I could find the following correct way to deserialize JSON string:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonAdaptersSampleClass());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
SampleClass obj1 = gson.fromJson("generated_json_string",ImmutableSampleClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try GSON library for converting JSON to your existing class object.

http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I am using Gson to convert object to Json string, and again string to object.

Comment: Type collectionType = new TypeToken<LoanRepayment>() {}.getType();
        LoanRepayment repayment = GsonUtils.createGson().fromJson(loanRepayment, collectionType);  are you doing it like this?

Comment: I have included my implementation to convert Json string into object in the description. Could you tell what is wrong there, and how I could correct it.

Comment: can you paste here your json?

Comment: {"var1":["a","b"],"var2":"abc","date1":"Sep 16, 2016 12:51:00 AM"}

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.