# Gson TypeToken with dynamic ArrayList item type

Tags: java, reflection, arraylist, gson

I have this code:

```
Type typeOfObjectsList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myClass>>() {}.getType();
List<myClass> objectsList = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfObjectsList);
```

It converts a JSON string to a `List` of objects.
But now I want to have this `ArrayList` with a dynamic type (not just `myClass`), defined at runtime.

**The `ArrayList`'s item type will be defined with *reflection*.**

I tried this:

```
    private <T> Type setModelAndGetCorrespondingList2(Class<T> type) {
        Type typeOfObjectsListNew = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType();
        return typeOfObjectsListNew;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. This is the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: {....my json....}
```

Comment: That's an SQLException. It has nothing to do with the code you've posted. Show us the JDBC code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's not! I just want to have that `TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>()` code accept dynamic Arraylist type.
somthing like this: `TypeToken<ArrayList<Class.forName(MyClass)>>`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The syntax you are proposing is invalid. The following

```
new TypeToken<ArrayList<Class.forName(MyClass)>>
```

is invalid because you're trying to pass a method invocation where a type name is expected.

The following

```
new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>()
```

is not possible because of how generics (type erasure) and reflection works. The whole `TypeToken` hack works because `Class#getGenericSuperclass()` does the following

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
> (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the Type object returned
> must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source
> code.

In other words, if it sees `ArrayList<T>`, that's the `ParameterizedType` it will return and you won't be able to extract the compile time value that the type variable `T` would have had.

`Type` and `ParameterizedType` are both interfaces. You can provide an instance of your own implementation (define a class that implements either interface and overrides its methods) or use one of the [helpful factory methods that `TypeToken` provides in its latest versions](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html). For example,

```
private Type setModelAndGetCorrespondingList2(Class<?> typeArgument) {
    return TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, typeArgument).getType();
}
```

Comment: I think it's possible, using the technique shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson

Comment: @BenoitDuffez Careful. The answer you linked is doing something different. It's using an actual `Class` object, so Gson can very well know what type to deserialize to. In the OP's question, they want to do it without using the `Class` object and only through the type argument, which isn't available within the method itself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: You're absolutely right. I thought that putting the class was an acceptable price to get this to work. But indeed, the linked answer does something different from what the OP asked for. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 91):

Since Gson 2.8.0, you can use [`TypeToken#getParameterized(Type rawType, Type... typeArguments)`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java#L310) to create the `TypeToken`, then `getType()` should do the trick.

For example:

```
TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, myClass).getType()
```

Answer (score 33):

**Option 1** - implement `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` yourself and pass it to Gson.

```
private static class ListParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {

    private Type type;

    private ListParameterizedType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {type};
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

    // implement equals method too! (as per javadoc)
}
```

Then simply:

```
Type type = new ListParameterizedType(clazz);
List<T> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Note that as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), equals method should also be implemented.

**Option 2** - (don't do this) reuse gson internal...

This will work too, at least with Gson 2.2.4.

```
Type type = com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null, ArrayList.class, clazz);
```

Answer (score 9):

### With kotlin you can use a below functions to converting (from/to)  any (JsonArray/JsonObject) just in one line without need to send a TypeToken  :-

#### Convert any class or array to JSON string

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T?.json() = this?.let { Gson().toJson(this, T::class.java) }
```

> Example to use :

```
 val list = listOf("1","2","3")
 val jsonArrayAsString = list.json() 
 //output : ["1","2","3"]

 val model= Foo(name = "example",email = "t@t.com") 
 val jsonObjectAsString = model.json()
//output : {"name" : "example", "email" : "t@t.com"}
```

#### Convert JSON string to any class or array

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> String?.fromJson(): T? = this?.let {
    val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
    Gson().fromJson(this, type)
}
```

> Example to use :

```
 val jsonArrayAsString = "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]"
 val list = jsonArrayAsString.fromJson<List<String>>()

 val jsonObjectAsString = "{ "name" : "example", "email" : "t@t.com"}"
 val model : Foo? = jsonObjectAsString.fromJson() 
 //or 
 val model = jsonObjectAsString.fromJson<Foo>()
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
public <T> List<T> listEntity(Class<T> clazz)
        throws WsIntegracaoException {
    try {
        // Consuming remote method
        String strJson = getService().listEntity(clazz.getName());

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(strJson).getAsJsonArray();

        List<T> lst =  new ArrayList<T>();
        for(final JsonElement json: array){
            T entity = GSON.fromJson(json, clazz);
            lst.add(entity);
        }

        return lst;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WsIntegracaoException(
                "WS method error [listEntity()]", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code with ' public <T>' in the method works using Java generic methods, documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with Guava's more powerful [`TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html):

```
private static <T> Type setModelAndGetCorrespondingList2(Class<T> type) {
    return new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}
            .where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, type)
            .getType();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl` workes. No need for custom implementation

```
Type type = ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List.class, new Type[]{childrenClazz}, null);
List list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Can be used with maps and any other collection:

```
ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(Map.class, new Type[]{String.class, childrenClazz}, null);
```

Here is nice demo how you can use it in custom deserializer: 
[Deserializing ImmutableList using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706772/deserializing-immutablelist-using-gson)

Answer (score 3):

in kotlin you can

```
inline fun <reified T> parseData(row :String): T{
   return Gson().fromJson(row, object: TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it. You just need to parse first your data into an `JsonArray` and then transform each object individually, and add it to a `List` :

```
Class<T> dataType;

//...

JsonElement root = jsonParser.parse(json);
List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
JsonArray rootArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
for (JsonElement json : rootArray) {
    try {
        data.add(gson.fromJson(json, dataType));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return data;
```

Comment: try / catch inside loop is very inefficient.

Comment: try / catch inside or outside the loop makes no difference to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Fully working solution:

```
String json = .... //example: mPrefs.getString("list", "");
ArrayList<YouClassName> myTypes = fromJSonList(json, YouClassName.class);


public <YouClassName> ArrayList<YouClassName> fromJSonList(String json, Class<YouClassName> type) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, type).getType());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward & simple in Kotlin.

```
val typeDataModelClass = Array<DataModelClass>::class.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually i have made extension functions to resolve this , saving a list to SharedPrefrence and retrieve them in anyplace in the app like this :

use this to Save a List to SharedPref. For example :

```
fun <T> SaveList(key: String?, list: List<T>?) {
val gson = Gson()
val json: String = gson.toJson(list)
getSharedPrefrences(App.getAppContext() as Application).edit().putString(key, json).apply()}
```

return the list in any place from sharedPref. like this :

```
fun Context.getList(key: String): String? {
 return getSharedPrefrences(App.getAppContext() as Application).getString(key, null)}

inline fun <reified T : Any> String?.fromJson(): T? = this?.let {
val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
Gson().fromJson(this, type)}
```

Usage in Saving and Getting List from Saved one is like :

```
saveList(Consts.SLIDERS, it.data)  

SetSliderData(this.getList(Consts.SLIDERS).fromJson<MutableList<SliderResponseItem>>()!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is json string data to convert in arraylist model

```
String json = getIntent().getExtras().getString("submitQuesList", "");
Type typeOfObjectsList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Datum_ques>>() {}.getType();
submitQuesList = new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfObjectsList);
```