# Convert JSON to Nested Object (generic object) by using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I wanna create an parser for parse JSON by using Gson.

The first `IParser.java`

```
public interface IParser<T> {
    public T parse(String json);
}
```

The second `Parser.java`

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Parser<T> implements IParser<T> {

    @Override
    public T parse(String json) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
        MyJson<T> jsonParsed = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<MyJson<T>>() {
        }.getType());

        System.out.println(jsonParsed.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

The third `MyJson.java`

```
public class MyJson<T> {
    private int status;
    private T data;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And `User.java`

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long usrId;
    private String usrNm;
    private String usrPwd;
    private String usrEml;

    public User() {

    }

    public long getUsrId() {
        return usrId;
    }

    public void setUsrId(long usrId) {
        this.usrId = usrId;
    }

    public String getUsrNm() {
        return usrNm;
    }

    public void setUsrNm(String usrNm) {
        this.usrNm = usrNm;
    }

    public String getUsrPwd() {
        return usrPwd;
    }

    public void setUsrPwd(String usrPwd) {
        this.usrPwd = usrPwd;
    }

    public String getUsrEml() {
        return usrEml;
    }

    public void setUsrEml(String usrEml) {
        this.usrEml = usrEml;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [usrId=" + usrId + ", usrNm=" + usrNm + ", usrPwd="
                + usrPwd + ", usrEml=" + usrEml + "]";
    }
}
```

My JSON String:

```
{
    status: 200,
    data: {
        usrId: 2,
        usrNm: "John",
        usrPwd: "123",
        usrEml: "john@test.com"
    }
}
```

---

I wanna parse above jsonString to `MyJson<T>` object.

I do:

```
MyJson<T> jsonParsed = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<MyJson<T>>() {
            }.getType());
```

=> `Gson` parses my `User` in `MyJson` to `LinkedTreeMap`

It mean: `Object data = jsonParsed.getData();` => data instance of `LinkedTreeMap`

What I want: data instance of `User`

But, when I try:

```
MyJson<User> jsonParsed = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<MyJson<User>>() {
            }.getType());
```

**gson works fine.**

So I wanna know that How can I make gson works fine with the first way (use T instead of User) because I wanna parse other object by using **Parser**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer is: You can't do that because of type erasure. The `TypeToken` hack Gson uses only works when the type is explicitly passed. `T`'s type is completely erased at runtime.

Comment: Dup: [Gson typetoken with dynamic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylists-type)

Comment: Your solution could not solve my problem. :(

Comment: It's not a solution; its explaining that, again, you *can't* do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem. :D

Comment: @JackDuong Can you share your solution? As i am facing the same problem. I am getting the LinkedTreeMap instead of my object instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public T parse(String json, Type type) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
    MyJson<T> jsonParsed = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    System.out.println(jsonParsed.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Using:

```
User user = myJson.parse(jsonString, new TypeToken<User>() {
        }.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted by others the problem is that the `TypeToken` has to be instantiated with all concrete types (i.e. not parameterized with any `T`). So you need the caller to instantiate the `TypeToken` for you ("you" being the `Parser` class here).

John's accepted answer works (if you ignore the fact that it returns `null` and print the result instead), but I think it's nicer to enforce the `Type` parameter compatibility with the returned type, like this:

```
public T parse(String json, TypeToken<MyJson<T>> typeToken) {
    MyJson<T> deserializedMyJson = gson.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType());
    return deserializedMyJson.getData();
}
```

And it will enforce at compile time that any call to `parse()` is passed a correct `TypeToken`, so that something like

```
A a = parser.parse(jsonString, new TypeToken<MyJson<B>>(){});  // incorrect
```

will fail at compile time, while something like this (assuming the `parse()` method takes a `Type` as parameter):

```
A a = parser.parse(jsonString, new TypeToken<MyJson<B>>(){}.getType());  // incorrect too, but will compile
```

will only fail at runtime (when trying to cast the `B` result from `parse()` execution into the `a` variable of type `A`).