# Gson serialize to LinkedTreeMap instead of my Entity

Tags: java, android, rest, serialization, gson

I'm trying to consume a REST service in an Android application, but am having problems in serializing an ArrayList:

**My RESTful service returns:**

[image]

**My Android application receives:**

[image]

I'm using Gson library for serialization of my objects and certainly the problem is related to it. In this sense I tried to make Serializer as follows:

```
public class MySerializer<E> 
    implements JsonSerializer<Collection<E>>, JsonDeserializer<Collection<E>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<E> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<E>>(){}.getType();
        return context.deserialize(json, type);
    }
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Collection<E> src, Type typeOfSrc, 
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<E>>(){}.getType();
        return context.serialize(src, type);
    }
}
```

Registered the apapter (`registerTypeAdapter(ArrayList.class, new MySerializer<Object>())`), but this not work...

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gson TypeToken with dynamic Arraylist's type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylists-type)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change the gradle version to an updated version and check whether the issue is resolved.

I too had the same issue and it got resolved when I changed the gradle version from 1.5.0 to 2.1.0