# Unable to serialize response from API into my class using Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, spring

Good Afternoon!

I am attempting to call an outside API that returns a list of stock related. I have had success calling the API and am able to return a string, however when I try to serialize the response into my NewsDTO class, I am returning null for all properties in my NewsDTO.

Here is what the resposne looks like when the api is called:
[Response Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t5zg.png)

Here is my NewsDTO:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class NewsDTO implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String source;
}
```

Here is my controller that makes the calls:

```
@RestController
public class StockApiController {
    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apikey;
    
    @GetMapping("/news")
    public List<NewsDTO> getStockNews() throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        String newsUri = "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/markets/news";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        httpHeaders.set("X-RapidAPI-Key", apikey);
        httpHeaders.set("X-RapidAPI-Host", "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com");

        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

        String response = restTemplate.exchange(newsUri, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class).getBody();

        List<NewsDTO> newsDTOList = mapper.readValue(
                response, new TypeReference<List<NewsDTO>>() { }
        );

        return newsDTOList;
    }
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried several things including wrapper my List in a wrapper class, however this was unsuccessful.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34578452/4216641) (and its answers) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You don't need to perform the mapping yourself; `RestTemplate` is fully equipped to handle deserialization for you.</s>

```
List<NewsDTO> newsDtos = restTemplate.exchange(newsUri, HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<NewsDTO>>() {}).getBody();
```

Per your comment, I've reviewed the schema and found it slightly off.  The error you got when you tried my recommendation indicates that the mapper is trying to deserialize into an array but instead got a single object.

If you look at the response schema, it returns a single object that contains two fields, `meta` and `body`.  `body` is a list of what you have defined as NewsDTO.  Here's an update that should solve this for you.

```
@Getter
@Setter
class RapidAPIResponse {
    //  The only thing that matters are the field names, meta and body.  The deserializer is going to take data from the meta section of the JSON payload to map that to the class of the meta field.
    private Meta meta; // maps to the meta field of the response
    private List<NewsDTO> body; // maps to the body field of the response
}

@Getter
@Setter
class NewsDTO {
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String source;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Meta {
    private String ticker;
    private String version;
    private Integer status;
    private String copywrite;
}

RapidAPIResponse rapidAPIResponse = restTemplate.exchange(newsUri, HttpMethod.GET, request, RapidAPIResponse.class).getBody();
```

Now you'll get back a RapidAPIResponse, it contains a field called body that is your array.  You just have to create a model that represents the response.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really appreciate it. I tried your suggestion and recieved the following exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.fortuna.web.stockInformation.dto.NewsDTO>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`). Any suggestions? 

I verified that that properties names match and they were correct.

Comment: @MattDecker See my updates, I didn't look close enough but your model didn't accurately represent the response payload.  This should help you through it