# Serialization of ArrayList (generic types) with GSON

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, gson

I want to serialize a java object to JSON with Google's GSON library. It works fine except when a ArrayList occurs. GSON isn't able to handle the generic type of the ArrayList. @Yavor Georgiev described a solution with the registerSerializer(...) method, but this method doesn't exist in the new releases.

```
gson.registerSerializer(ArrayList.class, new CollectionSerializer<Object>());
```

http://hashtagfail.com/post/44606137082/mobile-services-android-serialization-gson

In my case the ArrayList is nested in a class three layers under the object, which is passed to `toJSON(...)`.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

The structure is like this:

```
public class Data() {
    @Expose
    privat int number = 8;
    @Expose
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
}

public class Foo() {
    @Expose
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
}

import java.awt.Point;
public class Bar() {
    @Expose
    ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList()<>;
}
```

Comment: Please refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type

Comment: In his case he can specifies the type directly, because he only wants to convert the object `src` like `toJSON(src, type)`. But in my case the object `data` hasn't the type `ArrayList`, it's `Data`.

Comment: read the api on GsonBuilder.  the registerTypeAdapter method seems promising

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering an Adapter.

```
new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new JsonSerializer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return context.serialize(src);
            }
        })
```

Comment: But I am not sure this work for you already tried egisterSerializer(ArrayList.class, new CollectionSerializer<Object>());  which I think does the same thig