# List<Type> and java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap

Tags: java, json, gson, javabeans, classcastexception

Below my function,

```
public <T> List<T> jsonToListBean(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();     
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();       
    List<T> returnValue = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
    return returnValue;
}
```

but the system returns this exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap

I notice also that if I use the following line code

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ShapeBean>>(){}.getType();
```

it works, but my target is to be absolutly  as generic as possible to make my code more efficient.

How should i change my code to make usable also passing the type "T" instead the "ShapeBean"?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with GSON but you could try to implement some method of `TypeToken` that makes use of `clazz` or create `listType` yourself. One thing we're doing with Jackson is `Class<? extends Object> arrayClass = Array.newInstance( clazz, 0 ).getClass()` ,pass `arrayClass` to Jackson and finally return `Arrays.asList( parsedArray )` where `parsedArray` is what Jackson returns. Something similar might be possible with GSON - if you need that fallback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson TypeToken with dynamic ArrayList item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type)

Comment: it does not solve my problem

Comment: How you are calling `jsonToListBean(..)`?

Comment: List<ShapeBean> listaBean = jsonToListBean(jsonMessage, ShapeBean.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to kan's link below the code:

```
public <T> List<T> listEntity(String jsonCommand, Class<T> clazz) {

    List<T> lst =  new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        // Consuming remote method
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(jsonCommand).getAsJsonArray();

        for(final JsonElement json: array){
            Gson g = new Gson();
            T entity = g.fromJson(json, clazz);
            lst.add(entity);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return lst;
}
```

check also this:
[Gson TypeToken with dynamic ArrayList item type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type)