# Handle Whole Type Name For Nested Classes

Tags: java, reflection, gson

I use some nested classes like List, MyObject ...

Then I can find the type of them with using:

```
Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
```

But when I try to handle it with generic types like:

```
public static <T> T findClass(Class<T> resultClass)
    {
        //E.g. resultClass = String.class; Expect: List<String>
        Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();
    }
```

It doesn't work for me.

In here, I wonder two things.

1. Can I fix this problem?
2. Can I describe a path like `Class<List<String>>` in java?

Comment: No. If that was possible, there was no need for `TypeToken`.

Comment: If you know what the Type possible values are, you could always use `instanceof` to check the types against a known set of possible values

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303909/2711488), `TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, resultClass).getType()` would work since Gson 2.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)'s comment, I've just solved it like below:

```
public static <T> Set<T> fromJsonToSet(Class<T> resultClass)
{
    Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(Set.class, resultClass).getType();
    ...
}
```