# Convert Arraylist to JSONARRAY in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

**AFTER CONVERTING I AMD GETTING THESE BACK BLASH WANT TO REMOVE IT**
 `["{\"INFO_ID\":\"1\"}"]`

**this is how i converting**

`JSONArray InfoIdJsonArray1 = new JSONArray(arraylist);`
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (example):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with `Gson` library easily

**Gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

**Usage**

```
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    String jsonArrayString = (new Gson()).toJson(myList);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This's a helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048178/4611919)  to converting (from/to) json.
And for disable escaping HTML characters :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

or made a custom escaping characters as below :

```
val gson =
        GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(String::class.java, CustomeEscapeSerializer()).create()
```

```
class CustomeEscapeSerializer : JsonSerializer<String?> {
    override fun serialize(
        s: String?,
        type: Type?,
        jsonSerializationContext: JsonSerializationContext?
    ): JsonElement {
        return JsonPrimitive(s?.let { escapeJS(it) })
    }

    companion object {
        fun escapeJS(string: String): String {
            var s = ""
            val escapes =
                arrayOf(
                    arrayOf("\\", "\\\\"),
                    arrayOf("\"", "\\\""),
                    arrayOf("\n", "\\n"),
                    arrayOf("\r", "\\r"),
                    arrayOf("\b", "\\b"),
                    arrayOf("\\f", "\\f"),
                    arrayOf("\t", "\\t")
                )
            for (esc in escapes) {
                s = string.replace(esc[0], esc[1])
            }
            return s
        }
    }
}
```