# Room Db TypeConverter for cutom object

Tags: android, android-room

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "words_table")
data class Word(

    @PrimaryKey
    var word: String,

    var date: String?,
    var definition: String?,
    var examples: List<String>?,
    var partOfSpeech: String?,
    var pronunciation: String?,
    var syllables: Syllables?,
    var synonyms: List<String>?
) : Serializable
```

```
data class Syllables(
    var count: Int?,
    var list: List<String>?
): Serializable
```

I want to store this object in database, however, I cannot figure out how would the **TypeConverter** for it look it. Currently, I have a **TypeConverter** class which converts a list into json and vice versa. That is working fine, but this **Syllables** object has an **Int** and a **List**.
I am trying following code but this doesn't work for **Syllables** object

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringListToJson(value: List<String>?) = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToStringList(value: String) =
        Gson().fromJson(value, Array<String>::class.java).toList()

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromSyllables(value: Syllables?) = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun toSyllables(value: String) =
        Gson().fromJson(value, Array<Syllables>::class.java).toList()
}
```

Comment: You can convert `List<>` to a `TypeToken`

Comment: 'doesn't work for Syllables object' -> How do you mean that?

Comment: @Blackbelt It gives following error
**Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it**

Comment: @gtxtreme How so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TypeConverter for 'Syllables'. You only need for 'list'.

```
class Converters {

private val gSON = Gson()

@TypeConverter
fun fromList(list: List<String>?): String? {
    return if (list != null)
        gSON.toJson(list) else null
}

@TypeConverter
fun toList(s: String?): List<String>? {
    return if (s == null) arrayListOf() else {
        val listType: Type =
            object : TypeToken<List<String?>?>() {}.type
        gSON.fromJson(s, listType)
    }
}
}
```

and in 'Syllables'

```
data class Syllables(
var count: Int?,
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
var list: List<String>?
): Serializable
```

Comment: It's still giving **Cannot figure out how to save this field into database** error. I replaced my **Syllables** class with yours but it still isn't working. I also updated **Converts::class**

Comment: Have you added @TypeConverters(Converters::class) annotation in the database abstract class?
abstract class DatabaseName : RoomDatabase() { ...

Comment: Yes. TypeConverters are working fine for when it's a simple list. However, in case of this specific object, it doesn't work

Comment: Your question was incomplete.

Why don't you try Kotlin Serialization:

   @ TypeConverter
    fun fromSyllables(syllables: Syllables?): String? =
        if (syllables != null) Json.encodeToString(syllables) else null

    @ TypeConverter
    fun toSyllables(s: String?): Syllables? = if (s != null) Json.decodeFromString(s) else null